# Where are these old Yugoslavian monuments?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, landmarks, balkans

I came across a [list of old Yugoslavian monuments](http://www.cracktwo.com/2011/04/25-abandoned-soviet-monuments-that-look.html) that look quite interesting. Actually, I already saw the one in Podgarić and it was really impressive. Now I wanted to locate the rest of them, but wasn't really successful. I can't find half of them on Google Maps. Either the location is not known at all or there are more than one location with the same name. Therefore, I'm looking for the exact coordinates of the following monuments:

**Petrova Gora**
[image]

**Grmeč**
[image]

**Ilirska Bistrica**
[image]

**Košute**
[image]

**Korenica**
[image]

**Makljen**
[image]

**Kadinjača**
[image]

**Brezovica**
[image]

**Ostra**
[image]

**Nikšić**
[image]

**Zenica**
[image]

Comment: I seem to remember, from old news articles, that they are old monuments remembering distant communist-related events.

Comment: +1, absolutely SUPERB question!  I agree with MastaBaba that these would be artefacts from the Soviet era, but that's a guess and nothing more.

Comment: two of them are listed here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_War_II_monuments_and_memorials_in_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina

Comment: Only Bulgaria of the former communist states in Europe has any old monuments to rival those of Yugoslavia. I haven't visited any Yugoslav ones but I've seen the lists in websites and books and I think they are the best, but if you're interested in such things, you definitely ought to check out the Bulgarian ones too.

Comment: You have inspired me: [What did these monuments of former Yugoslavia look like before they were destroyed?](https://www.quora.com/What-did-these-monuments-of-former-Yugoslavia-look-like-before-they-were-destroyed)

Comment: @GayotFow by Soviet era, do you mean before Yugoslavia left Comintern in 1948?

Comment: @phoog Russians refer to two eras: Soviet and Federation (the current one). There have been no monuments (that I'm aware of) of that idiom constructed in the Federation era. I have been to lots of them and all will give the construction date on the cornerstone or marker.

Comment: @GayotFow what does that have to do with Yugoslavia?

Comment: I don't remember the context, if there even was one. Comments are second class citizens (Jeff Atwood).

Comment: @GayotFow my point is that communist != Soviet, especially where Yugoslavia is concerned, a country that was not aligned with the Soviet Union.

Answer (score 12):

These are old Yugoslavian War Memorials (or at least most of them).  Somebody created a great google map overlay of these:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zxPqN7FUTnEs.kTu_C4z_ZK5c

for some reason I am struggling to get the exact coordinates from that map, but you can zoom in all the way on each of them to see the actual monument at a decent enough zoom level.

Comment: aw man, I love these questions, and you beat me to it. Well found.

Comment: Yeah, I love these questions too, especially when I have some time to spend researching the answer :)

Comment: On my computer, you can (single, left) click on any individual pin and a sidebar will expand, showing the exact coordinates. e.g. http://frg.li/f42.png

Comment: For some, but not all of them

Comment: Ah. Good catch, @AleksG. I clicked on one pin which had the coordinates in the "description" field and mistakenly assumed it'd be the case for all of the pins. One method which *does* work to get the coordinates for each point is clicking the dropdown menu in the upper right corner of the panel on the left, then choosing "download KML". The downloaded file contains the coordinates for each point. Here's a [pastebin of the KML file](http://pastebin.com/GTyy9hwn).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a list of all monuments coordinates except Brezovica.

It is partially based on @Aleks G's [link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1jc_EZ7RlwFagkZa0V7fu3z8WBQ8) and @davidvc [pastebin of it](https://pastebin.com/GTyy9hwn), however, some coordinates there are misleading. For such ones, the proper coordinates were found and the source or proof is given.

- Petrova Gora ([45.316426, 15.805206](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/45%C2%B018%2759.1%22N+15%C2%B048%2718.7%22E/@45.3162491,15.8038526,317m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]
- Grmeč ([44.687329, 16.4376500](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/44%C2%B041%2714.4%22N+16%C2%B026%2715.5%22E/@44.6870969,16.4373881,226m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]
- Ilirska Bistrica ([45.568796,14.240245](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/45%C2%B034%2707.7%22N+14%C2%B014%2724.9%22E/@45.5686978,14.2391317,304m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]
- Košute ([43.627796, 16.691636](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/43%C2%B037%2740.1%22N+16%C2%B041%2729.9%22E/@43.627796,16.690851,226m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]

  (source and proof: [photo sphere by Jeremy Blencowe](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/43%C2%B037%2740.1%22N+16%C2%B041%2729.9%22E/@43.627815,16.691595,3a,75y,177.83h,58.1t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-fiCT2QJzrpM%2FVjh9l_2k1KI%2FAAAAAAAADtg%2F0j0q0G0FIRs!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2F-fiCT2QJzrpM%2FVjh9l_2k1KI%2FAAAAAAAADtg%2F0j0q0G0FIRs%2Fw203-h101-n-k-no%2F!7i9728!8i4864!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) from top of it)
- Korenica

  [image]

  according to [link](http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/korenica-monument44.676515.852144.676515.8521) it was destroyed and its location was [44.6765 15.8521](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/44%C2%B040%2735.4%22N+15%C2%B051%2707.6%22E/@44.6732579,15.8320494,3170m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0):

  > I've been to Korenica and asked a dozen of people in the village, they
  > say it has been torn down. You may correct me if I'm wrong. But I've
  > spend half a day looking for the monument.

  Picture:

  [image]
- Makljen ([43.842705, 17.597120](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/43%C2%B050%2733.7%22N+17%C2%B035%2749.6%22E/@43.842705,17.5951514,565m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)) (source: [annotated in Wikimapia as "destroyed monument"](https://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=43.843643&lon=17.600527&z=16&m=b&show=/17035739/sr/SRUSENI-SPOMENIK-NA-MAKLJENU))

  [image]
- Kadinjača ([43.911942, 19.742889](https://www.google.com/maps/place/43%C2%B054%2743.0%22N+19%C2%B044%2734.4%22E/@43.9119434,19.7421035,203m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en)) (it is a part of bigger monument ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadinja%C4%8Da)))

  [image]

  [Proof](http://www.worldarchitecturemap.org/buildings/kadinjaca-monument) (note the cirles on the pavement):

  [image]
  <sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2033/2968312921_6b729fcc8b.jpg))</sub>
- Brezovica (missing)

  [image]

  So far: it is likely not in Brezovica. This image is from [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/139119075958767521/) and it is annotated as "1st PARTISANS BRIGADE MONUMENT in Brezovica, Croatia", however,there is only a "Monument to Sisak Detachment" (depicted below, [source Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Yugoslav_World_War_II_monuments_and_memorials_in_Croatia), location [45.502663 16.458433](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/45%C2%B030%2709.6%22N+16%C2%B027%2730.4%22E/@45.502663,16.4569729,407m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]

  **UPD:** as @phoog noted there are many places named Brezovica ([list of them in Wikipedia](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)). [The Wikipedia article](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%A8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B5)) for one of them (Brezovica, Kosovo or Брезовица_(Штрпце) in Cyrillic) contains picture of the monument:

  [image]
- Ostra ([43.911496, 20.516597](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/43%C2%B054%2741.4%22N+20%C2%B030%2759.8%22E/@43.911496,20.5158106,225m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]

  Source and proof ([geolocated photo on Panoramio](https://ssl.panoramio.com/photo/53019053)):

  [image]
  <sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://static.panoramio.com.storage.googleapis.com/photos/large/53019053.jpg))</sub>
- Nikšić ([42.763139,18.959556](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/42%C2%B045%2747.3%22N+18%C2%B057%2734.4%22E/@42.7630609,18.9589816,180m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]
- Zenica ([44.244945,17.960287](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/44%C2%B014%2741.8%22N+17%C2%B057%2737.0%22E/@44.244855,17.9595346,225m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0))

  [image]

For more see ["Yugoslav World War II monuments and memorials" in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_World_War_II_monuments_and_memorials).

Comment: There seem to be roughly a dozen places called *Brezovica* in former Yugoslavia, mostly in Croatia and Serbia.  See https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brezovica. The Serbian page has more links for the Serbian places, but is in the Cyrillic script. An image search turns up at least two other pictures of the same monument, both somewhat less covered in graffiti.